# How to create a random user with cookie without log in

Tags: asp.net, ajax, session, cookies, webusercontrol

Hi I have a shopping web site and I want to create random user per computer with cookie or session But I can not create randomly. Could you guys help me to create a user per computer then add items to basket. I have basket codes Just need to create user per pc without log in...

Here is how do I create random Session ID

```
>> public void generate(){
>> SessionIDManager Manager = new SessionIDManager();
>> string NewID = Manager.CreateSessionID(Context);
>> userId.Text = NewID.ToString();
>> }
```

I call this in page load i say if(!ispostback){generate()}

so now when i refresh website id also gets refresh How can I control it if its same pc hold the session Id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try serialising the basket object and placing that into a cookie. When the user performs a checkout then create a user if needed and convert cookie basket to order in db.

You will need to start by trying to write some code though, then come back if you're still stuck.

**UPDATE**

The sessionId is created for each browser session, if you close the browser then reopen it you'll get a new sessionId, using the sessionId to identify a user is only going to work as long as the user doesn't close the browser. You could store the sessionId in a cookie and check the cookie when a user returns

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserId");
myCookie["SessionId"] = NewID.ToString();
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

But personally I think you should look at this from a different angle.

**UPDATE 2**

Try this, the sessionId will be the same when you click refresh until you close the browser.

```
public void generate(){
    var sessionId = Session.SessionID;
    userId.Text = sessionId;
}
```

Comment: There wont be user log in only session. my code works like this ; AddToBasket Button calls ajax button click function which is add to basket(){} which is sending ID product name... to webservice Here I only need random username per user. I was gettin ip before but it makes 1 pc per network so i need id per user without log in or anything for example if I enter the website my name will be user1 if u log in yours will be user2

Comment: in my basket table I have UserName productId productName and things. to show them in cart I control username so I need random sessionID to control username per product added to basket. Everything works I just need random UserName per User

Comment: I'm a bit far to cookie and session things. Can't look from too many different angles. I'm trying to make something simple to help me to create user per browser as u said. But even the refresh button changes the Id.btw when ı refresh The Id changes in textbox (userId). forexample first it comes like 1234 then i click refresh it gives 9874 but in url there is something like long code and it does not change.

Comment: public void generate(){
    var sessionId = Session.SessionID;
    userId.Text = sessionId;
} this thing is worked for me dude u rock thank you very much for it :) u saved the day. :D if u can help me to look from another angle to do this code much better i would like to see it =)

Comment: As I've said for basket information just store the basket object in a cookie, do some searching for "c# storing object in cookie", something like this article will help http://usefulscripts.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/how-to-store-and-object-in-cookie-in-asp-net-c/    just do some reading and try writing code, if you get to a point where you can't do something, post the code what you have got in a new question and I'm sure someone will help.